# bootstrap .input-append trouble

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make some simple tweaks to my layout using twitter bootstrap, but using the 'input-append' class is bugging me.  I'm sure the answer is very simple, but I'm new at this and I've been spending waaaay too long trying to find an answer.

I want the text input, the button and the End Text div on the same row, and I want the button appended to the text input.

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdavh/azF8w/2/

...Focusing on the div around the button:

```
<div class='span2'>
  <input class="btn btn-primary span2" type="submit" value="Search" />
</div>
```

If I change it to

```
<div class='span2 input-append'> ...
```

The button takes the right shape but is separated from the text input

If I take off the span2 and change it to

```
<div class='input-append'> ...
```

Then the button is appended correctly, but then the following 'End Text' block is pushed to the next line.

I'll spare you all of the other permutations I've tried.  I've searched but can not find a working example.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try below code:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <form>
        <div class='span3 input-append'>
            <input class="span2" id="main_search" type="text" />
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Search" />
        </div>
        <div class='span2'>
            <a class='littleNote' href=''>End Text</a>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Adit, this was just the right configuration.  As a note to others who may look at this, I had to change the `<div class='span3 input-append'>` to `<div class='span5 input-append'>` because the text input with appended button needed a span5 to fit into.  Otherwise, they overlapped the following 'span2' div.

Answer (score 0):

For adding buttons to input elements you need to use the input-append (or -prepend). Such as

```
  <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span2" id="appendedInputButton" type="text">
    <button class="btn" type="button">Go!</button>
  </div>
```

Also shown under "Extending form controls" in the docs [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)

Keep in mind though that the appended button adds an extra width to the input control, so to say, which you need to take to account when specifying the span*-width for your divs. I.e. set a span*-width on your input-append div wide enough to contain both the input element and the button.
Adit did this with a span3 in his example.